# Can not open PDF file using WebView

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I was trying to show pdf file using a url in webview. Although the WebView is loading webpage like google.com, it does not load anything or throw any exception when I try to load the url of the pdf.

The url loads pdf in google chrome desktop browser, so I guess the problem is not with the url itself.

Here's what I've coded so far:

**`onCreateView()` of Fragment that loads the pdf**

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_brochure, container, false);
        webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
//        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf");
//        webView.loadUrl(brochureUrl);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        return view;
    }
```

**Layout (xml file):**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/purple_500"
    tools:context=".ui.project_details.project_details_pages.BrochureFragment">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest file (only the portion that I think to be relavant)**

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        ...
        ...
        ...
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf document.

Comment: @blackapps, it can. although I'm not sure if the display mechanism is same as a standard pdf viewer.

Comment: No. It cannot. A WebView is for html documents. And the example in the answer does not display pdf but html as a google pdf to html converter is used as you can see on the url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There some issue while loading pdf with webView. You can use the following code to solve your problem. This method takes the help of drive to view pdf in webView.

```java
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String pdf = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: it worked! however, I also had to make some minor adjustments. I had to set webView's layout_height to 'match parent' and load the url after I was done with making changes to webview.getSettings(). I thought the .load() might invoke a thread and so the order might not matter. but now I think that this might not necessarily be the case.

Comment: for android 7. It seems the horziontal scroll appeared un knownly. Which is very annoyying...